# No se puede leer la propiedad de un indefinido

Tags: typescript, poo, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

seguramente haya muchos problemas aquí, estoy empezando con la programación orientada a objetos, este es mi primer proyecto con este paradigma, y también es mi primer proyecto con typescript, así que no se si es un problema de conceptos o del lenguaje.

De manera que tengo una interfaz en un fichero

> classes.ts

:

```
export interface IBoard{

boxes: string[];

empty_boxes:boolean;

there_are_3_in_a_row: boolean;
```

};

en el mismo fichero tengo una clase llamada Game, la cual tiene un metodo "showboard"

```
    static showboard(board){
    console.log("\n")
    console.log(" "+ board.boxes[0] + " | " + board.boxes[1] + " | " + board.boxes[2])
    console.log(" "+ board.boxes[3] + " | " + board.boxes[4] + " | " + board.boxes[5])
    console.log(" "+ board.boxes[6] + " | " + board.boxes[7] + " | " + board.boxes[8])
    console.log("\n")
    };
```

en otro fichero he definido el objeto tablero:

```
import {IBoard} from "./Classes"

export let board: IBoard;

board.boxes=["-","-","-",
            "-","-","-",
            "-","-","-"];
```

finalmente en otro fichero llamo al metodo showboard, he probado pasando como argumento board, o board.boxes y me sigue devolviendo el mismo error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'boxes')

¿hay algo grave que me este perdiendo o simplemente me estoy planteando mal el proyecto?

Comment: ts no es python, así que intenta utilizar la nomenclatura correcta (de hecho, la misma que usan la mayoría de lenguajes más conocidos), las variables en `camelCase`, sin guiones ni guiones bajos y las clases en `PascalCase`, lo mismo pero con la inicial mayúscula En cuanto al error... has declarado el objeto `board` del tipo `IBoard` pero nunca lo has *instanciado*. Si no le asignas un valor, lo único que vale es `undefined`, que es lo que te dice el error. Esto es común a todos los lenguajes en realidad... sea orientado a objetos o no, debes instanciar las cosas: `board = new IBoard()` !

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu consejo de la forma de nombrar variables, no supuse que fuese propio de un lenguaje.

En lo respectivo al problema, al escribir la linea de codigo que me has recomendado, el editor de texto me esta reclamando  que IBoard hace referencia a un tipo pero lo estoy usando como valor, lo cual no entiendo.

Comment: Es difícil decirte exactamente lo que tienes que poner si no puedo ver cómo has declarado las cosas. Te recomiendo buscar acerca de cómo instanciar objetos en TypeScript, ya que según lo hayas declarado varía un poco. Imagino que si lo instancias así irá: `let board = {} as IBoard;`, pero realmente lo mejor que puedes hacer es empezar por el principio y aprender a instanciar objetos correctamente, en vez de copiar y pegar código que no entiendes.

Answer (score 1):

El objeto tablero está mal definido:

```js
import {IBoard} from "./Classes"

// declaras la variable, pero no le asignas valor
export let board: IBoard; 

// por tanto, board es undefined aquí
board.boxes=["-","-","-",
            "-","-","-",
            "-","-","-"];
```

Debes hacer algo como

```js
import {IBoard} from "./Classes"


export const board: IBoard = {
  boxes : [
    "-","-","-",
    "-","-","-",
    "-","-","-"
  ],
  empty_boxes: true,
  there_are_3_in_a_row: false
}
```

Comment: Eso mismo termine descubriendo, y efectivamente arregla el problema, muchisimas gracias Pablo.